# Is it possible to write a mercurial hook which would replace a certain macro pattern with the respective revision?

Tags: mercurial

Suppose, I have the following pattern in a comment in my code - `$REV$`. I would like to have a client side hook, which would replace it with something like `$REV[$ d3d004be40c5 $]REV$`. Any subsequent commits would assume that there is a revision between `$REV[$` and `$]REV$` and replace it accordingly.

I want to use a client side hook, because I do not want an extra commit for this mangling, hence it must be done on the client as part of the commit.

I reckon a precommit hook in python should be apt for the job, but I've just thought to seek for an advice before delving into it. Maybe there is a better way to do it like using an existing extension, for instance. If anyone has done anything similar - please share.

Thanks.

P.S.

I know this may seem strange to embed the revision within the source code, but please indulge me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[keyword](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) extension does what you want (though usefulness of this is really, really low).

Comment: plus one for pointing out that the usefulness is low.  With a DVCS environment you're **much** better off putting it in the working directory on update rather than actually storing it in the code.  You can easily do this with a hook like 'update = hg id >> VERSION.txt` and if VERSION.txt is in your hgignore you won't accidentally commit it.